# iOS5: UIScrollView dispaying and scrolling differently from iOS4

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiview, ios5

This is a curious one.

I have an IBOutlet UIScrollView `playScrollView` whose height is exactly 1/3 of it's contentSize's height. The app is in landscape. I call this code...

```
[playScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0.0f, page * PLAY_VIEW_PAGE_HEIGHT,
                                              480.0, PLAY_VIEW_PAGE_HEIGHT)
                           animated:animated];
```

... (the int `page` ranges from 0 to 2) to start on `page` 1 (displaying the middle third) then go up or down as needed when the user presses buttons.

This works fine for iOS4 both device and simulator, and has been live on the app store for months with no problems. Even iOS5 devices are fine with existing builds, it was only when the app was recompiled for iOS5 that it stopped working correctly on iOS5 devices.

Since updating to XCode 4.2, This doesn't work for iOS5. It goes one `page` too low, showing the bottom page when it should show the middle. I can get the code to work for iOS5 (device and simulator) by changing `page` to `(page-1)`...

```
[playScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0.0f, (page-1) * PLAY_VIEW_PAGE_HEIGHT,
                                              480.0, PLAY_VIEW_PAGE_HEIGHT)
                           animated:animated];
```

...but of course this breaks iOS4, which works fine with the old code, but gets stuck one `page` too *high* with this new code. iOS4 and iOS5 are exactly `PLAY_VIEW_PAGE_HEIGHT` out-of-step (288 pixels, a third of the height of `playScrollView`). The same thing happens if I use `setContentOffset:` instead.

One other curious thing, probably the key to this. If I don't do the scrollRectToVisible at all, then iOS4 sits at the top of playScrollView, wheras iOS5 shows the middle third, (ie PLAY_VIEW_PAGE_HEIGHT pixels down).

I *could* detect the iOS and use different code for each, but that's a horrible kludge. If it's an iOS5 bug and they fix it in a future release, that would break the live app.

Has anyone any ideas, or noticed anything similar? Thanks.

Comment: Is your `UIScrollView` really 3 times the height of it's `contentSize`, or is it the other way around? I would expect the `contentSize` to always be >= the `UIScrollView`'s `bounds.size`.

Comment: Oops, serves me right for posting at 1am. Thanks, will fix.

Comment: Yep, lots of problems like this with iOS 5.  I've had to do `respondsToSelector:` all over the place to make the code work with both iOS 4 and iOS 5.

Comment: Have you filed a Radar? You might find it's been flagged already and there's a workaround.

Comment: Are you by any chance testing this on an armv6 device, like an iPhone 3G?

Comment: Yes, but the 3G (armv6) is the one that works fine for the original code. Also the armv7 iOS5 device was fine running the code that had been compiled on the previous XCode version.

Comment: Update: I just tried compiling with the Base SDK iOS 4.3 instead of iOS5, and then also supporting just armv6 instead of both armv6 and armv7. Both had no effect.

Comment: Looks like someone else is having a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813205 Have now flagged a radar, 10455447.

Comment: I did my best to recreate your configuration and my sample app works on iOS 4 and 5 just fine. Either I'm missing something in how you've configured things or you have an issue that's not evident from the description above.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for but useful nonetheless. It won't let me award you the bounty for a comment but here's an upvote.